# What is the ID or account card in Quan Zhi Gao Shou?

Tags: quan-zhi-gao-shou

In almost every episode of *Quan Zhi Gao Shou*, you see the players inserting what looks like an ID card into a card reader of some kind. However, it appears it's more of an account card than an ID card. As far as I can tell, it's a [Smart Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card) of some kind. I'm guessing it's a [physical token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_token) used for account security. I know this anime is based on a game, is it related to how the game is actually played?

- What is this card?
- Is it used for person/player identification, or just account authentication?
- Are card readers like this commonplace in Asia and/or China?
- Does this card control the account, or do you also have to use the account password?
- Are these account cards easily accessible, for example at the Asia-equivalent of Walmart?  In episode 2 or 3, we see the store owner's friend specially request her to provide an account, possibly indicating that they are hard to come by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The card is supposed to be for authentication purposes, saving data while still being online, as seen when Chen Guo took her card out but didn't log out of the game, so Ye Qiu could use her account to beat that guy at the start of the series.

I don't really remember if it's shown explicitly in the Chinese cartoon, but in the novel, they do go into the fact that players do sometimes forget to log out in-game and only take their card out, and subsequently get their accounts' items robbed. Also, it's explained in the novels that Glory is so widespread that every single net-cafe in China has a card reader on every PC, it's apparently Glory exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

It was common for games in arcades with some sort of progression to have cards to store your progress, like *Initial D* and *Maximum Tune* being examples. I also saw some shooter-style arcade games using this principle as well.

The usage in *Quan Zhi Gao Shou* is possibly a creative growth out of the same concept, but using a smart card to access an MMO is not a real-life thing.

I have seen smart cards used at LAN cafes for loading of credit/long-term memberships. It's also another place the idea may have come from.

Answer (score 0):

As the setting is pro gamers, the card is actually more like an ID card. It can be seen in the first(?) episode where the MC handed his original account over by simply handing his card over with no password or anything like that.

But it's probably an account card associated with the game, as switching accounts seem to work by switching out the card. as seen by how the pro players seem to insert a card to use their alt in some episodes i forgot which tho